# Laravel - How do I select all where column is equals to x or y or z (and on..)?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I'm working on Laravel framework version 5.1

How do I select all of my rows from an eloquent model where his `abc` column equals to `a` or `b` or `c`?

Sorry if I haven't explained myself very well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just chain the conditions:

```
App\SomeModel::where('abc', 'a')->orWhere('abc', 'b')->orWhere('abc', 'c')->get();
```

Or as an alternative you can use `whereIn` for more compact solution:

```
App\SomeModel::whereIn('abc', ['a', 'b', 'c'])->get();
```

Which checks if the value of the `abc` column is present in the array passed.

---

You can check out the Laravel documentation for more info on using [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: Thank you, I used the second method.

Comment: You're very welcome.